# branch cuts of log function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that I am going to take the branch cut of log as below

[image]

How would I define the range of the angles?

Generally, I know that I can take branch cuts to be any line connecting $0$ and $\infty$. In the case of the branch cut being the negative $x$ axis, I just take the range of the angle to be $(-\pi,\pi)$, but how would I possibly determine the range of the angle here?

Comment: Is this cut a straight line?

Comment: No, it is an arbitrary line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a curved branch cut, the allowed values of the argument (i.e. the imaginary part of $\log(z)$) will not be a fixed interval.  If $z$ is in the first quadrant and below the cut (i.e. can be connected to a point on the positive real axis by a path in the first quadrant that avoids the cut), the argument will be in $[0, \pi/2)$, if it is above the cut it will be in $[-2\pi, -3\pi/2)$.

Comment: How to get a more general result from this, can you give me any reference?

Comment: For example, what if my cut is a curve going through all of the four quadrants?

Comment: In general, you choose some starting point $p_0$ not on the cut and choose the value for $\log(p_0)$.  For  any other point $p$ not on the cut, take a pieewise smooth curve $\gamma$ going from $p_0$ to $p$ that doesn't intersect the cut, and let $$\log(p) = \log(p_0) + \int_\gamma \dfrac{dz}{z}$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any reference on this? I went through Stein, Simon and Gammelin, they seemed not have any detailed elaboration on this.

Comment: You might look at Marsden and Hoffman, "Basic Complex Analysis", section 2.2.

Comment: Thank you very much for being so patient and helpful

Comment: @RobertIsrael could you please explain why $z=1$ is not a branch point of $\log(z)$. The thing I can think of is that one can't factor $i\theta$ term from $\log(1+re^{i\theta})$, like in the case of  $\log(re^{i\theta})$. However, this is not very rigorous.

Comment: There's nothing special about $z=1$ from the point of view of $\log$.  The derivative $1/z$ is analytic there.

Comment: @RobertIsrael as far as I remember, the complex log $\log(f(z))$  can be defined on some domain where $f(z)\ne 0$, only if $\int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(\xi)}{f(\xi)}d\xi=0$ for any closed curve $\gamma$. So for $\log(z)$, $f(z)$ is just $z$ and the above integral is zero when choosing a closed loop $\gamma$ encircling the point $z=1$, and the argument of the log is nonzero too. Does this make seance?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your curve is given in inverse polar form $\theta(r)$.

Then, for any $z$, we can define $\log_r z$ to have an imaginary part $y$: $$\theta(|z|) +2 \pi n<y\le \theta(|z|) +2 \pi (n+1)$$ for some $n\in\mathbb Z$.